# Are this variables independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let be $(W,Y)$ a normal bivariate vector with correlation coefficient $\rho$ and variances $\sigma_W^2=\sigma_Y^2$.
Proof the independence of variables $W, (Y-\rho W)$.

I´m trying to proof that $Cov(W,Y-\rho W)=0$, because that implies that the variables are independent (because both are normal distributions).
I know that clearing the formula of correlation coefficient $Cov(W,Y)=\rho \sigma_W^2$, I think that maybe a variable change could find $Cov(W,Y-\rho W)$.

Comment: Be careful saying "because both are normal distributions".  That's not quite strong enough:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Answer (score 1):

No need to change variables; use the definition of correlation coefficient:
$$
\rho := {\mathop{Cov}(W,Y)\over\sigma_W\sigma_Y}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For any random variables $P,Q,R$, recall that: $\mathsf {Cov}(P, Q+R) = \mathsf {Cov}(P, Q)+\mathsf {Cov}(P,R)$